# AVPlayer streaming audio in background

Tags: ios, background, audio-streaming, avplayer

I have a problem with the AVPlayer playing in background mode, like a lot of people here and everywhere on the web. I've done what I think is supposed to work, but is still doesn't... I think my problem might be where I set and use my AudioSession and AVPlayer.

1) The "audio" key is in UIBackgroundModes of my Info.plist

2) AudioSession set like this in AppDelegate (initialised in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
AVAudioSession *audio = [[AVAudioSession alloc]init];
[audio setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[audio setActive:YES error:nil];
```

3) I use an AVPlayer (not AVAudioPlayer) also implemented in AppDelegate. (initialised in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, after the AudioSession), right after the AudioSession

```
// Load the array with the sample file
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://mystreamadress.mp3";

//Create a URL object.
self.urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];  
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlStream];
//Starts playback
[player play];
```

And still, the audio is suspended everytime the app goes in background (when I press the "Home" button).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the way, the problem was just with the simulator. Works fine on the iOS devices